# Как парсить номер телефона из теста?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте я сделал парсер видео с ютуба и там есть в описании номера телефонов и скайпы подскажите регулярное выражение или как парсить номера телефонов

в международном формате номера

обычный текст

По Всем вопросам пишите, звоните: 
Скайп : aigul_ar77
Тел : +77027637790

Comment: в международном формате номера

Comment: конечно решение если можно я незнаю как это сделать

Comment: Ну так опубликуйте исходную строку хотя бы в вашем вопросе. __UPD:__ в идеале вы должны были предоставить не только исходную строку, а и ваше решение, в котором у вас возникли трудности, и описать эти трудности. А вы пришли без ничего, и даже исходник не потрудились опубликовать. Такие вопросы тут бысто минусятся и закрываются.

Comment: я и незнал что писать незнал с чего начинать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
номер:    
$str = 'hghg +7(903)888-88-88 hgghg';
    preg_match('/((\+?\d+[\s\-\.]?)?((\(\d+\)|\d+)[\s\-\.]?)?(\d[\s\-\.]?){5,6}\d)/x', $str, $number);

    echo $number[0]; // +7(903)888-88-88

скайп:
$str = 'По Всем вопросам пишите, звоните: Скайп : aigul_ar77 Тел : +77027637790';
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.,\-_]{5,31}/i', $str, $skype);

echo $skype[0]; //aigul_ar77
```

Comment: а возможно спарсить скайпы?

Comment: @Petro Boyko добавил в ответ

Comment: подскажите еще как сделать урл кликабельным в инстаграм     `$clean_desc = str_replace('~@(\S+?)\s~', "https://www.instagram.com/\$1", $clean_desc);`

Comment: не получается так так парсит цыфры из текста  а если так то делает пропуски ~(\+[\d]+)~

Comment: вроде решилось вот так `preg_match("~(\+[\d- ()]+)~",$a,$m); $c = $m[1];`